# Translating custom \section format to titlesec

Tags: spacing, sectioning, formatting, indentation, titlesec

I have some custom `\section` formatting with a horizontal rule, and I'm trying to DRY out my code by using `titlesec` to define default formatting options. But I can't exactly reproduce what happens when not using `titlesec`. Here's an example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{xhfill}

\begin{document}

% Plain xrfill:
\section*{\large\normalfont First Section \xrfill[0.6ex]{0.4pt}}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

% Via titlesec:
\titleformat{\section}[runin]{\large}{\thetitle}{1em}{#1 \xrfill[0.6ex]{0.4pt}}
\section*{Second Section (\texttt{titlesec})}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

% Titlesec with a \\ at the end:
\titleformat{\section}[runin]{\large}{\thetitle}{1em}{#1 \xrfill[0.6ex]{0.4pt}\\}
\section*{Third Section (line break)}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

\end{document}
```

Note that using `titlesec` doesn't put the following text in a new paragraph. I tried to solve this with `\\` but that doesn't work either. What can I do to make this work the same way as it would without `titlesec`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `[display]` style instead of the `[runin]` style:

```
\titleformat{\section}[display]{\large}{\thetitle}{1em}{#1\space\xrfill[0.6ex]{0.4pt}}
\section*{Second Section (\texttt{titlesec})}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks! But the `titlesec` documentation seems to claim that `runin` mimics the default behavior. So why wouldn't this work with `runin`?

Comment: The `[runin]` style is equivalent to the standard classes' `\paragraph` style.  The default style (which in your example would also work) is `[hang]`, which is like the standard `\section` command (see p.3 of the docs). Because of the rule, I think that the `[display]` is more appropriate, though.